# Enlarge image in rmdformats::material theme

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am trying to enlarge my image in the rmdformats::material theme but i could not change the width, just the height of the image. I have tried using "px", "%", "in" and they all can't change the width of the image. Does anyone know what to do? Could it be the margins of the theme, if so, how do i change it?

Thanks

````
---
title: "Long Non-Coding RNAs"
author: "Name"
date: "date"
output: 
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: "tango"
    code_folding: hide
    number_sections: yes
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="200px", out.height="300px", fig.align="center", fig.cap="abc"}
library(knitr)
knitr::include_graphics("img.png")
````

Answer (score 0):

I had success adding this css code after the yaml header:

```
{css, echo = FALSE}

.pages .page img.image-thumb {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Default width is 250px as you may find it in ../rmdformats/templates/material/material.css